# CSS: make "overflow: hidden" hide the top instead of the bottom?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm using the "overflow: hidden;" CSS property on an image, but I'd like for it to cut off the top of the image rather than the bottom. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: give top and bottom class name for your top and bottom images and apply this property to specific class only.However post some code

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in the following ways:

**Using Image tag:**

HTML

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/1/" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**Using background image**

HTML:

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/1/);
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:bottom right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/475/